# Prove that constant 1-simplex is a 1-boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

I have been given the following question:
Given a topological space $X$, for any $x_0 \in X$ we have defined $\varphi_{x_0}:\sigma_1 \rightarrow X: (t_0,t_1) \rightarrow x_0$. Prove that $\varphi_{x_0} + B_1(X) = 0 + B_1(X)$.

I already have found that
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{x_0} + B_1(X) = 0 + B_1(X) &\iff \exists d \in B_1(X): \varphi_{x_0} = 0+d\\ 
&\iff \varphi_{x_0} \in B_1(X) \\
&\iff \exists e \in S_2(X): \varphi_{x_0} = \partial(e)
\end{align*}

But now I'm stuck, because I don't know how to explicitly or generally find such an $e$.
Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: First, $e$ should be a 2-simplex, not a 1-simplex. Second, you might as well try a constant 2-simplex, because you don't know that $X$ has any points other than $x_0$.

Comment: Yes, you're right thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that the constant path $c_x$ is a boundary.
In particular, $c_x$ is the boundary of the
$2$-singular simplex $\sigma$ which has the same image of $c_x$:
$$\partial_2(\sigma)=\sigma\circ(\hat E_0,E_1,E_2)-\sigma\circ (E_0,\hat E_1,E_2)+\sigma \circ(E_0,E_1,\hat E_2)=c_x-c_x+c_x=c_x.$$
Remember that the $q$-th boundary operator is defined as the map
$$\partial_q:S_q(X)\to S_{q-1}(X)\text{ such that}\\\partial_q(\sigma):=\sum_{j=0}^q(-)^j\sigma\circ F_q^j\text{, where }F_q^j:\Delta_{q-1}\to\Delta_q$$
is the face operator that maps the $(q-1)$-standard simplex $[E_0,\dots,E_{q-1}]$ to the $j$-th face of the
$q$-standard  simplex.